# Derive $\kappa(t)=\frac{\lvert \boldsymbol{a}(t) \times \boldsymbol{v}(t) \rvert}{v^3(t)}$ directly instead of proving it.

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

Let $\boldsymbol{r}(t)$ be a parametrised curve. Then,
$$\boldsymbol{\hat{T}}=\frac{\boldsymbol{r'}(t)}{\lvert \boldsymbol{r'}(t) \rvert }$$

$$\boldsymbol{\hat{N}}=\frac{\boldsymbol{\hat{T}'}(t)}{\lvert \boldsymbol{\hat{T}'}(t) \rvert } $$

$$\frac{d\boldsymbol{\hat{T}}}{ds}=\frac{\lvert \boldsymbol{\hat{T'}}(t) \rvert}{v(t)} \boldsymbol{\hat{N}}=\kappa(t)\boldsymbol{\hat{N}}$$

$$v(t)=\frac{ds}{dt}$$

$$\kappa(t) \equiv \frac{\lvert \boldsymbol{\hat{T'}}(t) \rvert}{v(t)} $$

$$\kappa(t)=\frac{\lvert \boldsymbol{a}(t) \times \boldsymbol{v}(t) \rvert}{v^3(t)}$$

I have seen some proofs of the last formula. But nevertheless I wonder whether it is possible to derive this formula directly. I think I need to clarify my intention: Suppose you know the definition of curvature as in the third equation but you don't know the formula for curvature as in the last equation. Then, someone asks you to give a formula for the curvature in terms of $\boldsymbol{r}(t)$ and its derivatives. How would you proceed, and how would you find this last equation? I think, it has to come from somewhere...

Well, I have got another, closely linked, question: Is there a formula for $$\frac{d\boldsymbol{\hat{T}}}{ds}$$ in terms of $\boldsymbol{r}(t)$ and its derivatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $$\frac{|d\boldsymbol{\hat{T}}|}{ds}= \frac{|d\boldsymbol{\hat{T}}|}{dt} \frac{dt}{ds}=\kappa(s)$$

Since we know $\boldsymbol{r}'(t)=\boldsymbol{T}(t)=\frac{ds}{dt} \boldsymbol{\hat{T}}(t)$

It is easy to see if we differentiate both sides with respect to $t$, we will get some relationship on the curvature.

$$\boldsymbol{r}''(t)=\frac{d^2 s}{dt^2}\boldsymbol{\hat{T}}(t)+\kappa  v^2\boldsymbol{\hat{N}}$$

We see that the second derivative of the position vector is related to the curvature in the above formula. To make it more clean, we want to eliminate the unit tangent vector, we can do this by crossing it with the tangent vector $\boldsymbol{r}'(t)$

$$\boldsymbol{r}'(t)\times\boldsymbol{r}''(t)=\frac{d^2 s}{dt^2}\boldsymbol{r}'(t)\times\boldsymbol{\hat{T}}(t)+\kappa  v^2\boldsymbol{r}'(t)\times\boldsymbol{\hat{N}}$$

Since the cross product of parallel vectors is the zero vector,

$$\boldsymbol{r}'(t)\times\boldsymbol{r}''(t)=\kappa v^3 \boldsymbol{\hat{B}}(t)$$

By taking the norm of both sides,

$$\kappa(t)=\frac{||\boldsymbol{r}'(t)\times\boldsymbol{r}''(t)||}{v(t)^3}$$

For your second question, using our expression above,

$$\boldsymbol{r}''(t)=v'(t)\boldsymbol{\hat{T}}(t)+v(t)\frac{d\boldsymbol{\hat{T}}(t)}{dt}$$

Rearranging,

$$\frac{d\boldsymbol{\hat{T}}(t)}{ds}=\frac{v(t)\boldsymbol{r}''(t)-v'(t)\boldsymbol{r}'(t)}{v(t)^3}$$

Comment: Wow, thanks. Nevertheless you I have now got the question: How to prove that $\lvert \boldsymbol{r}'(t)\times\boldsymbol{r}''(t)\rvert=\lvert v(t)\boldsymbol{r}''(t)-v'(t)\boldsymbol{r}'(t)\rvert$ without using curvature and your formulas above (that would be obvious). I somehow got the geometric intuition right (right triangle, sine,..), but how to do it rigorously?

Comment: @user50224 Hmm, this is actually not obvious without using the derivative of tangent vector. The problem here is $\boldsymbol{r}'(t)$ and $\boldsymbol{r}''(t)$ may not be orthogonal. And there is really not many expressions that involves the derivative of the speed $v'(t)$ (because it is usually ugly and messy to compute). For now I have an idea that maybe trying to express $\boldsymbol{r}'(t)$ and $\boldsymbol{r}''(t)$ in terms of Frenet frame (unit tangent, normal and binormal vectors) might work

Comment: I did it the following way: I factored the $r'(t)$ into $T \cdot v(t)$ and took the $v(t)$ out of the difference. Then I drew a right triangle with $r''(t)$ being the hypothenuse. $v'(t)$ is the tangential part of the acceleration vector. Then the opposite is $r''(t) \cdot \sin(\theta)$. -- Which is equal to the length of the cross product (don't forget the $v(t)$). Could this be made rigorous?

Comment: @user50224 What are the sides of the right angled triangle again? The hypotenuse is $r''(t)$, and what is the angle between?

Comment: The hypotenuse is $r''(t)$ and the adjacent is $v'(t) \cdot T$. The angle is just the angle between the acceleration vector and the tangent unit vector.

Comment: @user50224 I think the triangle may not always be right angled. It has to satisfy that $r''(t)-v'(t)r'(t)$ is perpendicular to $v'(t)r'(t)$, taking the dot product, we get $\hat{T}\cdot r''(t)=v'(t)v(t)$, which actually depends on the parametrization

Comment: Sorry, I wrote something confusing in my previous comment. I ment the $T$ to be the unit tangent vector but I forgot the caret. So, it should actually be that $v'(t) \hat{T}$ is perpendicular to $v'(t) \hat{T} - r''(t)$. Taking the dot product, now we get: $\left( v'(t) \right) ^2 = v'(t) \hat{T} \cdot r''(t)$. This can be simplified to yield: $v'(t)=\hat{T} \cdot r''(t)$. I think this is true since in case you write $r'(t)=v(t) \hat{T}$ and differentiate you get $r''(t)=v'(t) \hat{T} + v(t) \hat{T}'$. So, I think that this geometric approach gives the right answer at least intuitively.

Comment: Can this be made rigorously?  I don't think it would qualify as a proof. Or does it?

Comment: @user50224 Your geometric approach is correct. I'm not sure how to make it rigorous. But it is clearly related to the fact that $r''(t)=v'(t)\hat{T}(t) +v(t)\hat{T}'(t)$ representing the acceleration vector into two perpendicular components. But afterall it is hard to prove it without recognising the quantity of curvature

Comment: OK, thank you for your efforts!